# Trying to multithread using a global udpclient object, is there possible collisions issues?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm making a project in a p2p sharing system which will initiate a lot of sockets with the same ports. right now I'm using a global UdpClient which will use receive and sendasync methods on different threads with different endpoints. there is no usage of mutex as of now which is why I'm asking if collisions are possible using said object if I'm not changing the information inside this object

right now I tried only one example and it doesn't seem to collide although I don't trust one example enough for a full answer

Comment: If that object is used by multiple threads to only read information then doesn't require mutexes. If there is any one write, you need mutexes.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbdd9818-00f0-499f-a935-d8e555899d64/use-net-udpclient-in-a-multithreaded-env?forum=wcf

Comment: MrSpt: udpclient doesnt allow me to make the same socket multiple times which is why I was using a global udpclient.

kiner_shah: in that case can I just mutex the sendAsync method but receiving can go without problem?

Comment: another quick question, can I mutex only the send and receive methods instead of using mutex for the entire object?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, UdpClient is not thread safe. Thread safe objects should specifically mention that in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.-ctor?view=net-6.0), and UdpClient does not seem to do that.

So without any type of synchronization your code is most likely not safe. Testing is not sufficient since multi threading bugs are notorious for being difficult to reproduce. *When you write multi threaded code you need to ensure any shared data is synchronized appropriately*.

Using it within a lock is *probably* safe. But that is not a guarantee, UI objects are only safe to use from the thread that created the. Unfortunately that is not always well documented. A problem with locks is that it will block the thread, so locks are best used for very short and fast sections of code, not while doing long running operations like IO. And I don't think the compiler will even let you hold a lock while awaiting.

Another pattern is to use one or more concurrent queues, i.e. threads put messages on the queue, and another thread reads from the queue and sends the messages. There are many possible designs, and the best design will really depend on the specific application. However, designing concurrent systems is difficult, and I would recommend trying to create modules that are fairly independent, so you can understand and test a single module, without having to understand the entire program.

*Memory* is safe read concurrently. But the same does not extend to objects, since many object may mutate internal state when reading. Some types, like `List<T>`, specifically mentions that concurrent reads are safe. So make sure you check the documentation before using any object concurrently.

Comment: Well thanks, a few things before closing the question
1. If I'm using mutex can I mutex the recieve and send methods instead of the entire object? 2. Do other classes exist that can be used as udp sockets and are thread safe?

Comment: @raz `mutex` in c# is the cross-process version of a lock. If you are not doing anything cross-process you should be using locks, and you should be locking the resource you want exclusive access to. You cannot use locks/mutex to send anything. And there no thread safe udp sockets as far as I know. But you should probably consider using a higher level protocol/library, where there may be at least some that provide thread safe access.

Comment: Locking does not seem to wait for await but I don't think I'll use await (which if that's a mistake tell me). I can make one thread be the only one recieveing and share the information across threads as long as it's possible to only lock methods and not the whole instance.

Comment: ^ going to switch it, what if I'll just instead make a new send function with a concurrent queue which will have information and end points that other threads will update. This function will go through the queue and use sendasync to everything

Comment: @raz using a queue with a single sender sounds more sane. But I would check out existing libraries/protocols, like gRPC, http, MQTT, RabbitMQ etc, to see if any of them fulfills the requirements. An existing, and popular, library will likely be better designed, optimized, and tested than anything you would build yourself.

Comment: well I'm implementing an already existing networking protocol called mainline dht which opporates mostly on udp which seems like most of those classes don't support. A lot of them also use http (idk if it's optional or not) so it doesn't seem like it matches my requirements